# Can't access object laravel 5.3

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.3 mailables for sending emails.I want to pass data to view via with method.

I have create a mailable **MytestMail.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class MytestMail extends Mailable {
    public $dataArray;
    use Queueable,
        SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($dataArray) {
        $this->dataArray= $dataArray;
        
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build() {
  
        $address = 'test@gmail.com';
        $name = 'asasa';
        $subject = 'sasasasub';
      
      
        return $this->view('emails.myTestMail')
                ->from($address, $name)
                ->cc($address, $name)
                ->bcc($address, $name)
                ->replyTo($address, $name)
                ->subject($subject)
               ->with([
                        'name' => $this->dataArray->name,
                        'password' => $this->dataArray->password,
                        'E_id' => $this->dataArray->E_id,
                        'email' => $this->dataArray->email,
                   
                   
                    ]);
        ;
    }

}
```

Now i get an error

> Trying to get property of non-object

When i print_r  **$this->dataArray** i got an array with values

```
Array ( [name] => sdsdsds [E_id] => 0123 [password] => sdsd [username]
=> sdsdsdsds@sgxcxcxmail.com )
```

Please help me...Why i get this error message?

Comment: When returning the view shouldnt it just be `return view()`?, But i think the problem is youre accessing `$this->dataArray->name` as an object when you should try accessing it as an array like this `$this->dataArray['name']` at least thats what i assume from your code since you named it dataArray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you print_r it tells you the data type which is `->Array<- ( [name] => sdsdsds [E_id] => 0123 [password] => sdsd [username]=> sdsdsdsds@sgxcxcxmail.com )`, So when accessing the variable `$dataArray` be sure to access it as an array like so `$this->dataArray['name']` or `$this->dataArray['password']` etc...

Answer (score 2):

The issue is here

`'name' => $this->dataArray->name,`

you are trying to access `name` from `$this-dataArray` even though the `name` is an index of the array hence it is not a property of an object. The error message is self-explanatory.

> Trying to get property of non-object

What You should do instead is

`'name' => $this->dataArray['name'],`

Same goes to other array elements mentioned in your question.